# SObjectModel Javascript Library

Tags: reactjs, salesforce, visualforce

Is there a Salesforce library for their SObjectModel javascript object? Im working on an integration with salesforce and reactjs, but I'm having some trouble with the SObjectModel javascript object

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too too familiar with salesforce but it looks like there exists a few libraries for dealing with these objects.

Have you explored these?

https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce

https://github.com/ccoenraets/forcejs

Comment: Had't seen those libraries, but I will look into them. Thanks!